# BASH - Convert array to list

Tags: arrays, bash

i need convert an array to list and wrtiting in a file, but the result is without space or delimiter, eg:

```
 declare -a INSTANCEID=`ec2-run-instances --instance-count 2 --key xxx --instance-type t2.micro [...] ${AMIID} | ./getInstanceId.pl -`
```

if i make an `echo` of INSTANCEID i have `i-75bxxxfai-72bxxxfd`.
How can separate the two values (`i-75bxxxfa` and `i-72bxxxfd`) and writing in a file, one per lines?

I have tried with:

```
printf "%s\n"  "${INSTANCEID[@]}" > file.txt
```

but i have always the same output

Comment: The command launch two distinct instance, then i think is an array

Comment: @hellboy: I think you may want to re-check that, if they are distinct values, `printf "%s\n"  "${INSTANCEID[@]}"` would have already printed them on separate lines.

Comment: `echo 'i-75bxxxfai-72bxxxfd' |awk -v FS="-" -v OFS="\n" '{split($2,a,"i");print "$1" FS a[1], "$1" FS $3}'`

Comment: Thanks but is no correct, every instance start with `i-` and can finish with `i`. I need to use also a for because the instance they can be more than 2

Comment: Now, seems a string instead array, then i need separate the id's in a list, the id's starts with `i-` and can finish with `i`, can be more than two and can be long more characters

Comment: 2 instances `i-75bxxxfai-72bxxxfd` 3 instances `i-75bxxxfai-72bxxxfdi-72bxxxfdi` 4 instances `i-75bxxxfai-72bxxxfdi-72bxxxfdii-7894xxuk` etc...

Comment: @hellb0y77: Refer my answer below and see if that is what you expected

Comment: It's weird that `INSTANCEID` has concatenated values like so. I guess the fields are separated by a null-byte which is silently discarded by Bash's command substitution; if this is the case, your script will output ugly warnings when you upgrade to Bash 4.4. Anyway, you have a clear design flaw here! you need to fix it now! (and it will make your life much easier in the short and long run).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments over in the question description, OP wants to strip a string carrying instances.

A portable bash logic for this would be something like below. The below statements can be just run in command line.

```
$ INSTANCEID=i-75bxxxfai-72bxxxfd
$ IFS="-" read -ra instances <<<"$INSTANCEID"

$ for (( i=1; i<=$(( ${#instances[*]} -1 )); i++ )); \
    do printf "%s\n" "${instances[0]}-${instances[$i]//i} "; done
```

This will print the individual instances as

```
i-75bxxxfa
i-72bxxxfd
```

The idea here is

- Split the input string from `$INSTANCEID` variable with de-limiter as `-` and read them into an array(`read` command with `-a` for array-read operation). The array contains entries as `i`, `75bxxxfai`, `72bxxxfd`
- Now looping over the array `instances` over the total count `"${#instances[*]}" - 1` and forming the string as `"${instances[$0]}-${instances[$i]//i}"` which is the string `i` followed by de-limiter `-` and the subsequent elements of the array with `i` removed (`"${instances[$i]//i}"`)

You can see it working for any number of strings with multiple instance id's as:-

With 3 instances

```
$ INSTANCEID=i-75bxxxfai-72bxxxfdi-72bxxxfdi
$ IFS="-" read -ra instances <<<"$INSTANCEID"

$ for (( i=1; i<=$(( ${#instances[*]} -1 )); i++ )); \
    do printf "%s\n" "${instances[0]}-${instances[$i]//i} "; done

i-75bxxxfa
i-72bxxxfd
i-72bxxxfd
```

With 4 instances

```
$ INSTANCEID=i-75bxxxfai-72bxxxfdi-72bxxxfdii-7894xxuk
$ IFS="-" read -ra instances <<<"$INSTANCEID"

$ for (( i=1; i<=$(( ${#instances[*]} -1 )); i++ )); \
    do printf "%s\n" "${instances[0]}-${instances[$i]//i} "; done

i-75bxxxfa
i-72bxxxfd
i-72bxxxfd
i-7894xxuk
```

Read more about `bash`-  [`Shell Parameter Expansion`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

Comment: I have an error "`Syntax error, expected token` in line `do printf "%s\n" "${instances[$0]}-${instances[$i]//i} "; done`

Comment: @hellb0y77: Run it in a single line. `for (( i=1; i<=("${#instances[*]}" - 1); i++ )); do printf "%s\n" "${instances[$0]}-${instances[$i]//i} "; done` without any breaks, I added a line break for more readability

Comment: Working fine on my shell, `GNU bash 4.1.2`; Which version are you on
?

Comment: A more idiomatic loop: `for inst in "${instances[@]:1}"; do printf '%s-%s\n' "${instances[0]}" "${inst//i}"; done`.